# recursion, finding max, why is it not stopping?

Tags: python, recursion

I tried to find the maximum value in a sorted list. but the recursion is not stopping. please, can somebody help me?

```
A = [5,16,28,43,0,1]

start = 0
end = len(A) - 1
mid = 0

print mid

def search(start, end, mid):
  mid = int((start + end) / 2)
  print mid

  if A[mid] > [mid - 1] and A[mid] > A[mid + 1]:
    return A[mid]
  else:
    if A[mid - 1] > A[mid + 1]:
      search(start, mid, mid)
    else:
      search(mid, end, mid)
```

print search(start, end, mid)

Comment: You say, right in your problem statement, "sorted list".  But your list isn't sorted... what's up with that?

Comment: As ever, these kinds of assignments are pointless. The correct answer is `max(A)`, not some ugly recursive function.

Comment: @AdamSmith the correct answer is `max(A)` for production code.  The correct answer for a class in programming is whatever teaches the student.  That said, recursion for finding a max?  Why not binary search or a tree traversal or something where the recursion is actually helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with most of steveha's answer, but rather than picking off one element at a time I'd suggest dividing the list into halves and finding the max in each half.  You won't do any fewer comparisons, but the growth of the recursive stack will be `O(log(len(A)))` rather than `O(len(A))`.  For large lists this would be the difference between getting a stack overflow or not.

My implementation (which takes the list as an argument rather than expecting it to be global) follows:

```
def recursive_max(value_list, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return value_list[start]
    mid = start + (end - start) // 2
    lower_half_max = recursive_max(value_list, start, mid)
    upper_half_max = recursive_max(value_list, mid+1, end)
    if lower_half_max > upper_half_max:
        return lower_half_max
    else:
        return upper_half_max
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a "basis case" (where the recursion stops).

A natural basis case for this problem: if `start` is equal to `end`, just return `A[start]`

EDIT:

I just looked at this and the more I look the more confused I get.  Why are you using recursion to find a max?  It would make more sense to use recursion to do a "binary search" to find a value inside a sorted list.

If you want to really find a max value, that's pretty easy.  With recursion, we first want a "basis case" that gives us a trivial solution; then we want more code that will take us one step closer to that solution.

In this case, the basis case: we have only one value in the list; return it as the max.  To be specific, if the `start` and `end` together specify just one value, return that one value.  To make it proof against errors, might as well make this also handle the case where `start` is equal to or even greater than `end`.

Next remember the first value.

Next make a recursive call, but add one to `start` to reduce the size of the list we are considering.  This is the part that takes us one step closer to a solution.  Repeat this step enough times and we arrive at the basis case where there is only one value in the list to consider.

Finally compare the remembered first value with the result of the recursive call and return the larger of the two.

I'll lay it out in psuedocode for you:

```
BASIS CASE: start and end specify one value: return A[start]
save A[0] in a variable
save recursive_call_to_this_function(start+1, end) in a variable
compare two saved values and return the larger
```

Once you have tried to write the above in code, peek below this line for my working tested solution.

```
def recursive_max(start, end):
    if start >= end - 1:
        return A[start]
    x0 = A[start]
    x1 = recursive_max(start+1, end)
    if x0 >= x1:
        return x0
    else:
        return x1

print recursive_max(start, end)
```

Comment: also, the mid parameter is not very useful